# Problem converting tensorflow saved_model to tensorflowjs

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow.js

I want to convert trained python model (.pb) to tensorflowjs model. To accomplish this, first I saved the model with `estimator.export_savedmodel` function, then I run the `tensorflowjs_converter` command on Google Colab. However, no file is created for tensorflowjs. The conversion also gives a lot of warning and ends with an error.

Here is the full code, and please run to see the full output:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19k2s8eHpQY9Trps9dyaxPp0HqHWp5qpb

What is the reason of the problem and how can I fix it?

Part of the output:

```
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorflowjs_converter", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 638, in pip_main
    main([' '.join(sys.argv[1:])])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 642, in main
    convert(argv[0].split(' '))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/converter.py", line 591, in convert
    strip_debug_ops=args.strip_debug_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 435, in convert_tf_saved_model
    strip_debug_ops=strip_debug_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflowjs/converters/tf_saved_model_conversion_v2.py", line 141, in optimize_graph
    ', '.join(unsupported))
ValueError: Unsupported Ops in the model before optimization
ParallelDynamicStitch, StringSplit, Unique, RegexReplace, DynamicPartition, StringToHashBucketFast, ParseExample, LookupTableFindV2, LookupTableSizeV2, SparseFillEmptyRows, StringJoin, AsString, SparseSegmentSqrtN, HashTableV2
```

Edit:
Seems like it isn't supported:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2322

Comment: The error says it all. You are using in your model unsupported operators

Comment: How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your model has ops that are not supported by tensorflow.js yet. And seems like you missed the missing op name in the output you pasted. Please feel free to update the output with missing op name or file a feature request in the [tensorflow.js repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/new) with more details.

Comment: I've updated the missing op names. The link that I provide in the question has the all output.

Comment: Seems like it isn't supported https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2322